What is wrong in this schematic?
I'm working on a PCB for a nanogrid basically I need to monitor the current/voltage of the renewable energy sources and the battery storage (SoC) and the load state, also transfer all this information to an Arduino nano and handling a the relays.
So this is my current progress using easyEDA:



Looking at the body of the question, I can't seem to find a question being asked. While the title is Insights on nanogrid PCB, it isn't clear what sort of answer you are looking for.

You'd get better feedback if you labeled your ICs, right now it's hard to say what you are even doing. You probably do need decoupling capacitors on those ICs, and that big electrolytic isn't allowed on a USB device

@ChesterGillon I was looking for insights that means what is wrong what it is there to be improved/removed.

@user1850479 fair point on labeling the ICs, on your second point, how is that electrolytic connected to the USB device?

If the 5V doesn't come from the USB port, where is it from?

@MrGerber it comes from the arduino nano you see the pin on the bottom left?

And where does the Arduino get its 5V from?

Fair point but what it is wrong if it is connected to the USB? is the 330µF too big?

Are U1, U4, U8 and U16 all Allegro ACS712ELCTR-30A-T devices? The schematic only seems to give the part number for one of the four 8-pin devices in the Power measure section.

Yes @ChesterGillon they are all the same thats why i didnt re-highlight them

@KnowledgeSeeker Yes, as mentioned above the 330uF is way too big. Refer to the USB specifications. Allowed capacitance is from 1uF to 10uF

@MrGerber Thank you sir, is there anything else that should be done?

The big cap is on the USB bus which is not allowed. It is also not helpful to have huge electrolytic caps like that, so you should remove it. The ACS712ELCTR-30A-T needs decoupling, see page 1 of the datasheet for an example circuit.

Missing decoupling capacitors.

@winny where exactly should i place them?

@user1850479 what wrong with how i place the voltage inputs i think its correct no?

Just before the Vcc pin of every IC to ground. Moreover, you should have a ground plane.

No idea about voltage inputs. See here for decoupling: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150335/layout-of-decoupling-capacitors

The U1, U4, U8 and U16 devices are all Allegro ACS712ELCTR-30A-T devices, which is described as a Fully Integrated, Hall-Effect-Based Linear Current Sensor IC with 2.1 kVRMS Voltage Isolation and a Low-Resistance Current Conductor. The ACS712ELCTR-30A-T has a Current Measurement Range of ±30 A.
Comparing the schematic in the question against the ACS712ELCTR-30A-T datasheet shows the following which look wrong:

The internal resistance of the ACS712ELCTR-30A-T conductive path (from pins 1 and 2, to pins 3 and 4) for measuring current is 1.2 mΩ typical. Yet the schematic shows the connection sequence:

terminal block pin 1 -> 180 kΩ -> 10 kΩ -> ACS712ELCTR-30A-T pin 1 (IP+)
ACS712ELCTR-30A-T pin 3 (IP-) -> terminal block pin 2

Therefore can't see that the current can be measured.

All ACS712ELCTR-30A-T have their filter pin connected to the same 330 uF capacitor. Whereas the datasheet shows:

A maximum filter capacitor value of 470 nF in the graphs for the filter response.
The block diagram shows that the filter pin is connected to the internal signal path. Connecting the filter pins of multiple ACS712ELCTR-30A-T to the same filter capacitor is likely to mean the output voltage of the ACS712ELCTR-30A-T devices are likely to not represent the individual inputs.


One feature of the ACS712ELCTR-30A-T from the datasheet is:

The terminals of the conductive path are electrically isolated from the signal leads (pins 5 through 8). This allows the ACS712 to be used in applications requiring electrical isolation without the use of opto-isolators or other costly isolation techniques.

However, the schematic show pin 1 (IP+) is connected to an Arduino analogue pin via a 10 kΩ resistor and therefore the Arduino isn't electrically isolate from the power inputs. From the question the input voltage isn't specified, so not sure if the lack of isolation could be a safety issue.


I think the intent was to allow the ACS712ELCTR-30A-T devices to be used to sense external current and voltage. However, based upon the above don't think that the circuit will allow those measurements.

Thank you chester for your feedback, can you tell me how to fix each point you described im still confused on how to solve it to measure voltage and current? also why is making the same filter voltage the same across all the ACS712 a problem?

I mean for your first point : im entering from the positive pin of the ACS and leaving from its negative pin is that wrong? for the second point they are seperate inputs, why would the value of the capacitor influence the filter? for the third point : im stepping down the value of the input voltage using that voltage divider (10k & 180k) to get inputed as analog input for the arduino, why isnt there isolation ? the voltage wires are embedded in the PCB no?

@KnowledgeSeeker It's not some "voltage" you are placing at the filter pin, that pin carries the very signal that eventually appears at the device's output. See page 4 of the datasheet.You are connecting all the signals together into one node. Use individual filter capacitors for each device.

Ah okey i did it, but what about the first point that chester mentioned ? @SimonFitch

@KnowledgeSeeker I think Chester is trying to say that you should be passing current straight through the IC, in via IP+ and out of IP-, but you're not doing that. You've got some resistor voltage divider (such as R3 & U14) going on, which makes no sense. There shouldn't be any extra resistance in that current path.

why would that make a difference, i need the voltage divider so i take the voltage measure to send it the arduino nano? or should i place the resistors after the current sensing?
