Nanogrid management PCB review
I have made some progress on the PCB for a nanogrid consisting of solar panel, wind turbine, batteries, load (not yet connected) this board monitors the current/voltage of each components and sends them to an RPi through arduino nano, here is the latest update of what i made using easyEDA:

PS, so for each of the 3-pin input of each power supply, (pin-2  is the positive input, pin-3 is the ground of the supply , pin-1 is the pathway to charge the batteries).

Please clarifiy what voltage / current you expect to see in this system... the current sense traces are almost certianly far too thin. You also have an potential divider that won't work (top and bottom are connected to the same pin), and it's not got a reference, so it doubly won't work.

i expect to measure the voltage/ current of each components (PV, wind turbines, battery, load) , when you said current sense traces do you mean in the pin of the ACS ?Also whats wrong with the voltage divider? @Attie

Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/719298/what-is-wrong-in-this-schematic. Also the changes proposed in your previous schematic question hasn't been implmented.

about the decoupling capacitors? @winny

That and the voltage dividers.

@winny I made some significant changes , have a look again thx :)

Did you test the circuit on a protoboard or breadboard before making the PCB? If you want people to review your design, please also kindly provide the part number for U2-U4, U12-U13.

Still lacking decoupling capacitors, no ground plane and if those optocouplers are for isolation, you're breaking it with shared ground on both sides.

where should i put the decoupling capacitors is it for every Vcc? also what is that ground plane i thought i should just use GND where it is needed, why am I breaking the current sensors? @winny

U2-U4 are current sensors ACS756SCA-100B-PSF-T, U12-U13 are 1-channel-relay modules, i dont have access to a breadboard or anything im asking for guidance before i print this PCB this is my first time doing this. @hcheung

I told you in your schematic review. Search for decoupling capacitor here or google. Why are you using optocouplers if you share ground on both sides anyway? A mains connected board is not a beginner task.

@winny okey i will put the decoupling capacitor in series with the Vcc pins along with 5V, well my professor told me to do so I cant complain, when you are talking about optocouplers you are talking about U12-U13?

I read your previous post after my comment, and I think severals have point out the circuit doesn't work. ACS756 is a current sensor IC, it measure the voltage drop between IP+ and IP- over the internal shunt resistor of 1.2 micro-ohm. Your voltage divider of 180k/10k at IP- simply wrong, what voltage you are expecting on the Arduino input? Read the datasheet and try to understand how the chip work, and build a prototype before you make your PCB, otherwise you are simply wasting your time and waste everybody's time for reviewing it. Nobody would make an PCB without building a prototype first.

@hcheung , i only implemented this solution that was recommended in the previous post: "The voltage divider should be in parallel with your voltage source, i.e. "across" it. The current sensor should be in series with the source and load."

If IP+ and IP- have a shut resistor of micro-ohm, your voltage divider is not connect "across", you are connect in series with the shunt resistor. pull out a pencil and draw the shunt resistor and your voltage divider, based on the voltage and current that you are going to measure, do some calculation to see what current you are going to get with this configuration? and what voltage you are going to get at the Arduino input? I suggest you started with the fundamental by reading this.

Thank you so much @hcheung

@hcheung have a look at what i made now, thank you
